# How to get data collections within the JSON Object using async in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, asynchronous

My JSON data response from the server is

{
"isValid":true,
"count":3,
"code":200,
"data":[
{
"name":"xxx",
"department":"cse",
},
{
"name":"yyy",
"department":"it",
}]
}

```
<div *ngFor="let x of hotels$.data | async">
<hotel-list [listData]="x"></hotel-list>
```

i tried above but I am not getting results from loop

Comment: Could you post the code where you are fetching data from the server?

Comment: You need to add more information. What is `hotels$`? Is it an observable? What type? How is it retrieved from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've provided not enough of information, I'd suppose that you should do this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of (hotels$ | async)?.data">
```

because `hotels$` seems to be an observable but `hotels$.data` is not.